# When your vs.net project is type website, what's the namespace/dll you reference in your handler web.config?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler

When your vs.net project is type website, what's the namespace/dll you reference in your handler web.config setting?

you normally have to do:

```
"YourNameSpace.Class, Class"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you handler has no namespace you can just do:

```
<add verb="*" path="Handler.ashx" type="Handler"/>
```